# How can I find only keys from a multidimensional array that have a key as a child?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My code is finding all keys with a specific character from my multidimensional array:

```
<?
$array = ["farm"=>
              [
                "horse"=>
                 [
                  "rabbit"=>
                     [
                      "name"=> "alan",
                      "age"=> "21",
                      "size"=> "166",
                      "gender"=> "f"
                    ], 
              ]
           ]   
    ]; 

    function createList($array, $keySearch, $path=null) {
                  $result = [];
        foreach ($array as $key => $item) { 
            $basePath = $path === null ? $key : $path. "/" . $key;
            if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false)
                 $result[] = ['key' => $key, 'basePath' => $basePath];            
            if(is_array($item))
                 $result = array_merge($result, createList($item, $keySearch, $basePath));
        }
    return $result;
    }

    $keySearch = 'a';
    $res = createList($array, $keySearch);
    print_r($res);
```

https://eval.in/573212

My output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => farm
            [basePath] => farm
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => rabbit
            [basePath] => farm/horse/rabbit
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => name
            [basePath] => farm/horse/rabbit/name
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key] => age
            [basePath] => farm/horse/rabbit/age
        )

)
```

But I need only the keys, that have a key as a child. So in this case my result should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => farm
            [basePath] => farm
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => rabbit
            [basePath] => farm/horse/rabbit
        )
)
```

Comment: Why is Rabbit subordinate to Horse. That makes no sence, does it? Farms have Horses AND Rabbits but Horses do not have Rabbits. Maybe your original data creation is at fault here

Comment: I think i got you, Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for, please check and let me know. Just check your item has childs or not by using `is_array($item)` in the if condition.

[online Check](https://3v4l.org/A1J0T)

Just change the function:

```
function createList($array, $keySearch, $path=null) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) { 
        $basePath = $path === null ? $key : $path. "/" . $key;
        if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false && is_array($item)){
            $result[] = ['key' => $key, 'basePath' => $basePath];
        }       
        if(is_array($item))
            $result = array_merge($result, createList($item, $keySearch, $basePath));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Working very well!

Answer (score 0):

try changing  `if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false)` to  `if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false && is_array($item))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(is_array($item))` after `$basePath = $path === null ? $key : $path. "/" . $key;`

```
$array = ["farm"=>
              [
                "horse"=>
                 [
                  "rabbit"=>
                     [
                      "name"=> "alan",
                      "age"=> "21",
                      "size"=> "166",
                      "gender"=> "f"
                    ], 
              ]
           ]   
    ]; 

function createList($array, $keySearch, $path=null) {
              $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) { 
        $basePath = $path === null ? $key : $path. "/" . $key;
        if(is_array($item))
        if (stripos($key, $keySearch) !== false)
             $result[] = ['key' => $key, 'basePath' => $basePath];            
        if(is_array($item))
             $result = array_merge($result, createList($item, $keySearch, $basePath));
    }
    return $result;
}

$keySearch = 'a';
$res = createList($array, $keySearch);
print_r($res);
```

This will give you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => farm
            [basePath] => farm
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => rabbit
            [basePath] => farm/horse/rabbit
        )

)
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://eval.in/573231)